# AWS sdk for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm uploading a node.js file via elastic beamstalk CLI.  I'm using the sample given to me be AWS.

```
var http = require("http");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello Worlds");
  response.end();
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);
```

Everything works fine until I include the:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Then I get this error message.

```
502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.7
```

How do I fix this? I'm only uploading one file, server.js to beanstalk. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you ssh to the instance and see the logs in /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log?
I suspect you will need a package.json that installs aws-sdk as a dependency. Do you already have that?

Update 05/26:

I tried the following app. Below are the contents of various files in the app source zip.

package.json

```
{
   "dependencies": {
     "aws-sdk": "*"
    }
}
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello Worlds");
  response.end();
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);
```

.ebextensions/01-setup.config

```
option_settings
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
      option_name: NodeVersion
      value: 0.10.26
```

I am using Solution Stack "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.2 running Node.js" and the app with the above contents launches successfully.
Can you try looking at both files /var/log/node/nodejs.log and /var/log/npm-debug.log?

Comment: Hi my package.json already has that in my computer.  Then i uploaded the entire thing via elastic beanstalk command line

Comment: What does the nodejs log file say? Can you ssh to your instance?

Comment: I just ssh but I don't know how to access the log file?

Comment: Run vi var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log or use your favorite editor.

Comment: the file doesn't exists.  vi opens a new file up

Comment: what i did was 1.)use elastic beanstalk to upload file 2.) assign keypair to the ec2 instance 3.) ssh to ec2 instance 4.) starting isntall node software on

Comment: here is the ls of my directory AUTHORS      common.gypi    doc       Makefile-gyp  README.md  vcbuild.bat
benchmark    configure      lib       node          src        wscript
BSDmakefile  configure-gyp  LICENSE   node.gyp      test
ChangeLog    deps           Makefile  out           tools

Comment: I forgot the leading slash in the filename but I assume you must have correctly opened /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log and not var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

Comment: What is the name of your solution stack? There are multiple versions of nodejs solution stacks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54369/discussion-between-user1424508-and-rohit-banga).